# Can you connect Google Firestore directly to Google AutoML NLP for prediction?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have rows and rows of text stored in Firestore.
I have AutoML NLP trained model already.
I want to do sentiment analysis on the text in Firestore with AutoML NLP.

Is there a direct connection or do I have to have the data go through Google Cloud Storage first?

Ex:

1. Firestore => Cloud Storage => AutoML NLP => Prediction
2. Firestore => AutoML NLP => Prediction

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, [as per this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/datasets#import-data), importing training data into a AutoML dataset requires a CSV file stored in a Cloud Storage bucket. [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/automl/docs/prepare#csv) also confirms that the CSV file MUST be stored in a Cloud Storage bucket associated with your project.

So, there is no direct import from Firestore to AutoML. If you so require, I suggest you open [a Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/) with the [GCP AutoML team](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list).